# Is it possible for it to be inpenetrable?

Tags: database-design, security

I was wondering if it is possible to create some sort of database that is physically impossible to enter. While creating it you store some information in it and program it to spit that information after a period of time. But not even you can access it even if you wanted to, you have no choice but to wait.

Thanks.

Comment: Everything is possible, given enough time and money. Now, what's your actual question?

Comment: Vague memories of reading about FreeBSD having some sort of logging system that not even root can turn off without a reboot - too many suspicious unplanned reboots and the DBA would be looking at an audit - I was impressed when I read saw this - a quick Google revealed nothing but if you're interested, might be worth a search/look?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more suitable for a security site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, build it on a physical server.  Unplug the server and put the server in a time lock physical safe.  When the safe opens plug the server back in.

I can't imagine how it would be possible as a coded solution.

You might be able to do something with an encrypted database, if you had some way to tie the encryption to a specific date.  Doing that would be a question for [INFORMATION SECURITY](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Related [time-based encryption algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11416803/2112418)